# How to draw web elements on native camera?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, swift, wkwebview

I am developing both app applications and web applications, so I have a difficulty using camera sources from web app tools.
What I want is that I want to display text, images from web source using wkwebview on the native camera that is provided from ios & android library.
Is there any way to use web based languages(eg.javascript) to show elements on native camera.

Is it possible to draw images on native camera in my hibrid app like below image; (service name:)ZIGGAM (this app probably made through swift but i want to use swift and javascript)
and If it could, how do I draw web element(eg. div tag) on native camera?

cf. I use swift in xcode and java in android studio
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1tCq.png)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be, at least in Android, to create the Camera view that covers the entire page, and then have a webview that covers the camera. That way in your webview HTML you can set the background to transparent using rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) and then you can draw whatever you'd like on the screen. However, I feel there are much more streamlined ways to do what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for your words Da Mahdi03. What are more streamlined ways to do?